# text search function on java script area define issue

Tags: javascript, html

i have text search function in java script which can find the string and high lighted. the issue is that . i am using this function in chat . i need to find text only on chat box not to whole the page . i am new on j-query so i did not find where should i change . please look the code .

```
 <script>
   var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;`enter code here`
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
 </script>
```

please guide me how to use this on a particular area like any div with ID

Comment: How are you calling this function currently?? "*i am new on j-query"* - i don't see any jQuery in there... that's javascript

Comment: oh sorry can u please tell me how can i define area